# Dynamically changing the number of ticks in D3

Tags: d3.js

I try to dynamically change the number of ticks on an axis via an input field

```
// updated by an input field
var nNumberOfTicks;
function updatenumberofticks(nValue) { nNumberOfTicks = nValue; }

// definition of the axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .orient('bottom')
  .ticks(nNumberOfTicks)
  .scale(xScale);
```

but it doesn't work. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/stefanooo/cn2xo56w/3/.

This example works perfectly when changing xmin. What do I have to change to make it work for the number of ticks also?

Comment: The number you pass to `.ticks()` is only a hint for D3 -- there's no guarantee that you'll get exactly this number of ticks. The only way to do that is to set them explicitly through `.tickValues()`.

Comment: I know that, but the problem is not that the number of ticks is not exact - the problem is, it doesn't change, no matter what you enter into the input field. Initializing with `.ticks(2)` results in 3 ticks, but changing the input field doesn't change anything. Any idea?

Comment: Ah, well you also need to pass the new number of ticks to the axis -- http://jsfiddle.net/cn2xo56w/5/

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: Could you post that as an answer, please? Even if the OP might not reappear to accept the answer, future visitors at least get an obvious hint that the question is answered, and the answer can be upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the updated number of ticks to the axis component after changing it, e.g.

```
d3.select("#numberofticks").on("change", function() {
  updatenumberofticks(+this.value);
  vis.select('.xaxis').transition().call(xAxis.ticks(+this.value));
});
```

Complete example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cn2xo56w/5/).

Comment: Got a 404 on the fiddle link