# how to set d3 xAxis time scale ticks dynamically based on amount of data (ie. per hour for less than a days data, per day for everything over)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am creating a d3 line graph where users can input data over time. Because of this, I want to be able to dynamically adjust the xAxis number of ticks or tick intervals based on how much data exists.

Right now my ticks are set up with `d3.timeDay.every(1)` which is great except for on the very first day that a new user inputs data, because there will be no ticks until the next day.

I'd like to be able to configure it so that the tick interval is set based on the length of d.date so that if there is less than on day of data the interval should be `d3.timeHour.every(1)`

If you have a better or more efficient way of making sure there is still a tick with the date for day one data, please let me know, I'm not married to this strategy

I have tried using a ternary operator within the ticks so:

```
.call(d3.axisBottom(xScale)
  .ticks(dataPoints.date.length > 1 ? d3.timeDay.every(1) : d3.timeHour.every(1) )
  .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%a %b %d %Y')));
```

but I got a `t.range is not a function` error

Then I tried to use d3.range within the ticks and set the range for the current date to one month prior (using momentjs, `moment()` is the same as `new Date()` )

```
.ticks(d3.range( moment().subtract(1, 'months'), moment(), 1))
.tickFormat(d3.timeFormat(d3.timeFormat('%a %b %d %Y')));
```

but there were still no ticks for the first day because it's still on a one day interval

I also was looking at the stack overflow answer I saw here ([Dynamically changing the number of ticks in D3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26759809/dynamically-changing-the-number-of-ticks-in-d3)):

so setting `ticks()` to `nNumberOfTicks`

and then set nNumberOfTicks to my ternary operator

```
var nNumberOfTicks = dataPoints.date.length > 1 ? d3.timeDay.every(1) : d3.timeHour.every(1)
```

but then when it came to updating it onChange I couldn't figure out what the `updateNumberofticks` function should be, or what `this.value` should look like since I was using `d3.timeDay.every()` instead of a regular value so it didn't feel like it would be a good fit for my issue

```
d3.select('#nNumberOfTicks').on('change', function() {
  updatenumberofticks(+this.value);
  vis.select('.xaxis').transition().call(xAxis.ticks(+this.value));
});
```

I am also not even sure if going by d.date.length is even going to be effective since that's just the number of data entries not the number of unique dates, so if someone adds 3 new data points today d.date.length will be 3 but it's all still under one day

I just don't know how to check it against the value of the date key without it being unnecessarily complicated and I feel like there has to be a more efficient way, like maybe always have one tick out of range for the current day before the rest of the data?

this is my chart code (it is a multi line graph with nested data based on the key `d.mood`, xAxis is `d.date` yAxis is `d.level` an integer between 0 and 100), I've added a comment pointing to the specific relevant lines :

```js
var margin = {top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 80},
        width = 1050 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        let dataPoints = dataSet.map(function(d) {
            return {
                date: new Date(d.date),
                level: +d.level,
                mood: d.mood
            };
        });


        let xScale = d3.scaleTime().domain(d3.extent(dataPoints, function(d) { return d.date})).range([margin.left, width - margin.right]);
        let yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 100]).range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top]);

        let line = d3.line()
        .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.date)})
        .y(function (d) { return yScale(d.level)})
        .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)

    var svg = d3.select('#moodChart').append('svg')
        .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

    var dataNest = d3.nest().key(function(d) { return d.mood; }).entries(dataPoints) 

    let color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemePaired);

    let legendSpace = height / dataNest.length;

    svg.append('g').classed('data-points', true);

    dataNest.forEach(function(d, i){

        svg.append('path')
            .attr('class', 'line')
            .style('stroke', function() {
                return d.color = color(d.key);
            })
            .style('stroke-width', 3)
            .attr('d', line(d.values))


        svg.append('text')
            .attr('y', (legendSpace/5)+ i * legendSpace)
            .attr('x', width - (margin.right / 3) + 5)
            .attr('class', 'legend')
            .style('fill', function() {
                return d.color = color(d.key);
            })
            .text(d.key)

    });

////THIS RIGHT HERE

svg.append('g').attr('class', 'xAxis').attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(d3.timeDay.every(1)).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%a %b %d %Y')));


/// END OF XAXIS TICKS CODE 

    svg.append('g').attr('class', 'yAxis').call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));

    var points = svg.select('g.data-points').selectAll('dot')
        .data(dataPoints.filter(function(d) {
            return d.level;
        }))
        .enter()

    points.append('circle')
        .attr('r', 4)
        .attr('class', 'circles')
        .style('fill', function(d) { return d.color = color(d.mood)})
        .attr('cx', function(d) { return xScale(d.date); })
        .attr('cy', function(d) { return yScale(+d.level); })
```

I want the ticks on the xAxis set up so that on the very first day someone inputs data they will see a tick for that day, and as they add more data on different days the interval will be one tick per day

I know that because the data point shows up they could just assume it is for the current date but from a user experience standpoint it's not ideal to have the xAxis blank until they have at least two days worth of data